# Не получается подключиться к бд postgres(docker)

Tags: javascript, postgresql, docker, nestjs

Всем привет. Пишу сервер на nest, использую postgres и пытаюсь подключить elasticsearch. Для того, чтобы протестировать последнее нужно, как я понял, запустить docker контейнер. Я, вроде как, все сделал, но при запуске контейнера возникает ошибка `ERROR [ExceptionHandler] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432`. Я понимаю, что вопросов с подобной ошибкой много, но я пока не нашел ничего подходящего для себя + до этого все работало нормально. Единственное, я думал по поводу миграций бд. Могут ли они как-то мешать подключиться к бд?

.env

```
PORT=5000
POSTGRES_HOST=localhost
POSTGRES_USER=postgres
POSTGRES_DB=cp-itr
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=12345
POSTGRES_PORT=5432
SECRET=SECRET3
ELASTICSEARCH_NODE=http://localhost:9200
ELASTICSEARCH_INDEX=tasks
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:12.13-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

COPY ./dist ./dist

CMD ["npm", "run", "start:dev"]
```

docker-compose

```
version: '3.0'

services:
    main:
        container_name: main_nest
        build:
            context: .
        env_file:
            - .development.env
        volumes:
            - .:/app
            - /app/node_modules
        ports:
            - 5000:5000
            - 9229:9229
        command: npm run start:dev
        depends_on:
            - db_postgres
        restart: always
    db_postgres:
        container_name: db_postgres
        image: postgres:13
        env_file:
            - .development.env
        environment:
            PG_DATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data
        ports:
            - 5432:5432
        volumes:
            - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        restart: always
    nest-elasticsearch:
        container_name: nest-elasticsearch
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.0.1
        healthcheck:
            test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "curl --silent --fail localhost:9200/_cat/health?h=st || exit 1" ]
            interval: 50s
            timeout: 30s
            retries: 5
        environment:
            - cluster.name=cp-itr
            - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
            - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
            - discovery.type=single-node
        ports:
            - 9300:9300
            - 9200:9200
volumes:
    pgdata:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А почему POSTGRES_HOST=localhost разве не POSTGRES_HOST=db_postgres соединение же происходит в подсети docker

Comment: Я уже совсем запутался со всеми этими конфигурациями) Спасибо Вам большое. Даже немного стыдно теперь)